# How to use BrowserRouter if child routes has components attached?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am a newbie to react. I was following the tutorial [React Tutorial](https://vladimirponomarev.com/blog/authentication-in-react-apps-creating-components) to create a signup form. But then it is outdated. I am trying to redirect to the signup, login and home page on clicking the links using browser redirect. The tutorial as defined routes like

```
const routes = {
  component: Base,
  childRoutes: [

    {
      path: '/',
      component: HomePage
    },

    {
      path: '/login',
      component: LoginPage
    },

    {
      path: '/signup',
      component: SignUpPage
    }

  ]
};
```

The base component defines the navigation bars with links. This routes is then imported into the index page and used along with browser history which is outdated as per React Router v4. I wanted to use Browser Router but i am unable to figure out how to provide child routes with components attached.

I tried the following

Index.jsx

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render((
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Router>{routes}</Router>
  </MuiThemeProvider>), 
        document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Routes.jsx

```
const routes = <Route component = {Base}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path ="/login" component = {LoginPage}/>
        <Route path ="/signup" component = {SignUpPage}/>
    </Switch>    
</Route>;
```

But i knew from the start that this would not work and as expected it threw an error. `You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored` and Failed prop type: `The prop`children`is marked as required in`Base`, but its value is`undefined. Which I obvious because i have not mentioned anywhere about the child routes like the earlier version did. I tried looking into this [React training link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) as well but could find where to insert components to routes.

Any help will be appreciated.I am sorry if this question has already been asked but i could't find many tutorials or proper documentation regarding react router 4 which would help me.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're rendering `Base` without children, and in RRv4 you shouldn't be having nested routes.

Comment: Do you wanna generate the routes dynamically

Comment: Thanks for responding. @Melounek answer was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should erase `<Route component = {Base}>` and use `<Base>` instead